# Как правильно писать названия орденов Российской Империи?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать названия орденов Российской Империи? Например: "награждён орденом Св. Владимира 3-й ст."

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли вы найдёте сколь-либо авторитетные указания по поводу написания названий орденов давно не существующего государства. Геральдисты и историки геральдики такими вещами не заморачиваются, а ранее использовавшиеся "шаблоны" неприменимы к современной орфографии.
Меня лично ваш вариант написания ордена Св. Владимира вполне устраивает. Вопрос может возникнуть по поводу заглавной/строчной в слове "орден" и слове "святой", ну и в аналогичных случаях для других орденов. Аналогий с названиями современных российских орденов я побаиваюсь.

Могу сказать, что сейчас наметилась явная тенденция писать всё, что можно с заглавной (см., например, http://www.03www.su/rusnag/index.html), но это никак не согласуется с общим орфографическим духом. Я бы всё-таки "орден" писал со строчной, а "святой" - с прописной только в случае, если это первое слово после "орден" - т.е. начало названия.
Да, кавычки, разумеется не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Названия орденов не выделяются кавычками и все слова названия ордена, кроме самого слова "орден" пишутся с прописной буквы.